# Google Colab saveing as PDF using File->Print gives error

Tags: python, pdf, google-colaboratory

Recently I've finshed a project using Google Colaboratory  but I've encountered a strange error when  I've went to File->Print and tried to save it as PDF. The problem is that the section where it showes how my PDF will look like was normal, as it should be, but when I actualy downloaded it some pages didn't load up properly as you can see here:
[Page 14 of my Project before download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE9ZQ.png)

[Same page 14 but after download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe6IR.png)

And what it happens for page 14 in the second image happens for **mostly** all of the pages, only the first ones work but they get progressively worse. Any ideas?

Comment: this problem has nothing to do with programming and Stackoverflow is a portal for problems in programming. It looks liek problem with your local Operation System and installed programs for printers.

Comment: I've had issues with the Firefox print-to-PDF as well. Try using the system print dialog via the blue link on the right. But furas is correct; this has nothing to do with programming and is therefore off-topic here.